# Shiny - Assign Javascript Function to Individual Links

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, onclick

In the Shiny script below, the javascript function returns the id of the relevant 'a' tag when the hyperlink is clicked. This javascript function however works for all links on the page. If I wanted to limit which links this function was called up on how would that be done?

For example, in the script below I would only want the function to execute when either of the first three links are clicked but not the last two.

Note that this will ultimately be used on a dynamically generated table with hundreds of rows.

````
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tags$script(HTML(
        "$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function(evt){
    Shiny.setInputValue('clicked_text', evt.target.id);
  });
})"
    )),
    
    tags$a(href = "#", id = 1, "id is 1"),
    br(),
    tags$a(href = "#", id = 2, "id is 2"),
    br(),
    tags$a(href = "#", id = 3, "id is 3"),
    
    br(),
    tags$a(href = "#", id = 4, "id is 4, javascript function should be suppressed for this link"),
    br(),
    tags$a(href = "#", id = 5, "id is 5, javascript function should be suppressed for this link"),
    
    textOutput("clicked_text"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$clicked_text <- eventReactive(input$clicked_text, {
        input$clicked_text
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the `onclick` attribute:

```
tags$script(HTML(
  "function setinput(id) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('clicked_text', id);
  }"
)),

tags$a(href = "#", id = 1, onclick = "setinput(this.id);", "id is 1"),
```

Another possibility is to set a class to the elements you want:

```
tags$script(HTML(
  "$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'a .myclass', function(evt){
      Shiny.setInputValue('clicked_text', evt.target.id);
    });
  })"
)),

tags$a(href = "#", class = "myclass", id = 1, "id is 1"),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` condition for the `id` that you want to show the value.

```
output$clicked_text <- eventReactive(input$clicked_text, {
    if(input$clicked_text %in% 1:3) input$clicked_text
  })
```

Complete code -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$script(HTML(
    "$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function(evt){
    Shiny.setInputValue('clicked_text', evt.target.id);
  });
})"
  )),
  
  tags$a(href = "#", id = 1, "id is 1"),
  br(),
  tags$a(href = "#", id = 2, "id is 2"),
  br(),
  tags$a(href = "#", id = 3, "id is 3"),
  
  br(),
  tags$a(href = "#", id = 4, "id is 4, javascript function should be suppressed for this link"),
  br(),
  tags$a(href = "#", id = 5, "id is 5, javascript function should be suppressed for this link"),
  
  textOutput("clicked_text"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$clicked_text <- eventReactive(input$clicked_text, {
    if(input$clicked_text %in% 1:3) input$clicked_text
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If function would be one way, problem is that if I'm using this on dynamically generated tables with hundreds of links that would be an issue. I was hoping there was some way to call the function from the 'a' tag like an on.click event or similar. Then only have that on.click event coded into the specific links that I wanted to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Do you mean you don't know their `id`'s beforehand and can't use `1:3` ?

Comment: Correct, the IDs will be dynamically generated